# cv::Mat conversion to Eigen-Matrix and back

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen, eigen3

I have several feature vectors stored in a `cv::Mat` where, each row is a feature vector (several rows like this one here: `[ x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3.... ]`). I have to apply SVD on each feature vector and for that I use Eigen library. But, before applying SVD the feature matrix has to be converted to `Eigen::Matrix` form.

Later, I have to convert the SVD result back to `cv::Mat`.

Could anyone please suggest a nice way to do this? The reason I need it in `cv::Mat` form is because I have to input it to a Neural Network in OpenCV and only `cv::Mat` inputs matrices are allowed.

Thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV CV::Mat and Eigen::Matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783329/opencv-cvmat-and-eigenmatrix). No need to copy the data, use Eigen::Map. Look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783329/opencv-cvmat-and-eigenmatrix/21706778#21706778

Answer (score 6):

An example from http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=97516:

```
#include <opencv2/core/eigen.hpp>
cv::Mat_<float> a = Mat_<float>::ones(2,2);
Eigen::Matrix<float,Dynamic,Dynamic> b;
cv2eigen(a,b);
```

Also, [OpenCV CV::Mat and Eigen::Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783329/opencv-cvmat-and-eigenmatrix?rq=1) has a solution using an Eigen::Map.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code for eigen to cv:

```
template<typename _Tp, int _rows, int _cols, int _options, int _maxRows, int _maxCols>
void eigen2cv(const Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, _rows, _cols, _options, _maxRows, _maxCols>& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    if (!(src.Flags & Eigen::RowMajorBit))
    {
        cv::Mat _src(src.cols(), src.rows(), cv::DataType<_Tp>::type,
            (void*)src.data(), src.stride() * sizeof(_Tp));
        cv::transpose(_src, dst);
    }
    else
    {
        cv::Mat _src(src.rows(), src.cols(), cv::DataType<_Tp>::type,
            (void*)src.data(), src.stride() * sizeof(_Tp));
        _src.copyTo(dst);
    }
}
```

As you can see this performs a copy. With a matrix that small you shouldn't care, but you could change the code. to get the first column, use `cv::Mat::column()`.

Try one of these methods for cv to eigen:

```
template<typename _Tp, int _rows, int _cols, int _options, int _maxRows, int _maxCols>
void cv2eigen( const Mat& src,
               Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, _rows, _cols, _options, _maxRows, _maxCols>& dst )
{
    CV_DbgAssert(src.rows == _rows && src.cols == _cols);
    if( !(dst.Flags & Eigen::RowMajorBit) )
    {
        Mat _dst(src.cols, src.rows, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        if( src.type() == _dst.type() )
            transpose(src, _dst);
        else if( src.cols == src.rows )
        {
            src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
            transpose(_dst, _dst);
        }
        else
            Mat(src.t()).convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
    else
    {
        Mat _dst(src.rows, src.cols, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
}

template<typename _Tp>
void cv2eigen( const Mat& src,
               Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>& dst )
{
    dst.resize(src.rows, src.cols);
    if( !(dst.Flags & Eigen::RowMajorBit) )
    {
        Mat _dst(src.cols, src.rows, DataType<_Tp>::type,
             dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        if( src.type() == _dst.type() )
            transpose(src, _dst);
        else if( src.cols == src.rows )
        {
            src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
            transpose(_dst, _dst);
        }
        else
            Mat(src.t()).convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
    else
    {
        Mat _dst(src.rows, src.cols, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
}


template<typename _Tp>
void cv2eigen( const Mat& src,
               Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>& dst )
{
    CV_Assert(src.cols == 1);
    dst.resize(src.rows);

    if( !(dst.Flags & Eigen::RowMajorBit) )
    {
        Mat _dst(src.cols, src.rows, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        if( src.type() == _dst.type() )
            transpose(src, _dst);
        else
            Mat(src.t()).convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
    else
    {
        Mat _dst(src.rows, src.cols, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
}


template<typename _Tp>
void cv2eigen( const Mat& src,
               Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, 1, Eigen::Dynamic>& dst )
{
    CV_Assert(src.rows == 1);
    dst.resize(src.cols);
    if( !(dst.Flags & Eigen::RowMajorBit) )
    {
        Mat _dst(src.cols, src.rows, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        if( src.type() == _dst.type() )
            transpose(src, _dst);
        else
            Mat(src.t()).convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
    else
    {
        Mat _dst(src.rows, src.cols, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
}
```

**Source:** This code is taken from OpenCV itself, they use it internally as OpenCV can use libeigen for some tasks internally. I don't understand why format conversions to such libs and Qt are not exposed through the API.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! could you please tell me what is the "template" thing here? I am not yet at advanced level...

and also how do I convert cv::Mat to Eigen::Matrix....thank you for your inputs!!! @ypnos

Comment: and what is this "typename _Tp" and DataType<_Tp>

Please explain a little more....its very important...

Comment: You need to learn templates yourself. But using this code is rather easy and does not involve templates. E.g.: cv::Mat_<float> src; Eigen::MatrixXf dest(src.rows, src.cols); cv2eigen(src, dest);

Comment: I'll try this! Please also tell me a little on what is this "typename _Tp" and DataType<_Tp>....I don't understand...

Thank you...  @ypnos

Comment: Just read your favorite book about C++ templates. It is very basic C++ concept! About DataType see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html

Comment: Alright...I will go through some text. 
And any specific header files to use?? Other than Eigen/Dense ? 
@ypnos

Comment: If there would be any I would've stated it. Obviously you need using namespace cv; and the OpenCV core include.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [Mapping data from Eigen to OpenCV and back](https://computer-vision-talks.com/post/mapping-eigen-to-opencv/) article. It describe how to map data with less overhead. In the simplest case there would be no copy at all. It also deal with Eigen expressions as well:

```
// Unsharp mask
Eigen::ArrayXXd img, blur;    
eigen2cv(img) = cv::imread("lena.jpg");
cv::GaussianBlur(eigen2cv(img), eigen2cv(blur));

cv::imshow("sharpened", eigen2cv(1.5 * img - 0.5 * blur));
```

Comment: They the new header file you have been talking in your blog does not work with OpenCV 2.4.9. I just included the header Eigen2CV.h and g++ throws a bunch of weird errors.