# opencv3 failed in Mat::Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type) construct on vs2015

Tags: opencv, mat

Problem: Create a 4*4*4 array meets error with Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type) construct function in vs2015.

Refer the book *learning OpenCV3*, I can't create a 4*4*4 array with the following codes in vs2015. And the result of **m** shows rows=-1 and cols=-1. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

```
int sz[3] = { 4, 4, 4 };
cv::Mat m( 3, sz, CV_32FC3 );
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please describe the error that you get? From your screenshot I see that you are in the debugger, so compilation seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that rows and cols being -1 is the problem, it is not. For more than two dimensions, refer to size as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18883062/4883924) and it will be `m.size[0] == m.size[1] == m.size[2] == 4`.

Comment: Thank you! I have got it. Actually, the array has been created but I can not look up it through a simple way(such as std::cout). Thanks for your help again.