# Convert the cv::Mat of OpenCV to Eigen

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen, eigen3

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783329/opencv-cvmat-and-eigenmatrix) show us how to map the `cv::Mat` to Eigen matrix without copy the data, it works fine, but there are one thing I do not understand.

```
Mat A(20, 20, CV_32FC1);
cv::randn(A, 0.0f, 1.0f); // random data

// Map the OpenCV matrix with Eigen:
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>> A_Eigen(A.ptr<float>(), A.rows, A.cols);
```

The problem is, the `Mat A` do not tell the `A_Eigen` how many bytes per row it should take, as far as I know the `cv::Mat` of OpenCV may or may not do padding on each row, do  I need to tell the Eigen how many bytes per row (how?)?, or I can safely omit it?

Ps: I am using Eigen 3

Comment: I probably would use the [conversion functions](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp) given by OpenCV (second answer to the linked question). [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/daf/group__core__eigen.html#ga28d4c291bb74c3b915e2fd62f03906b1&gsc.tab=0)

Comment: @Miki Thanks, The opencv solution will allocated new buffer and copy the data(for dynamic matrix), but I want to reuse existing buffer, when training a lot of data, reduce the usage of memory is crucial, else it may throw bad_alloc exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `A.cols`, use `A.step` (or `A.step[0]` or `A.step[1]`?). If the OpenCV matrix is not [continuous](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#bool%20Mat::isContinuous%28%29%20const), then `m.step != m.cols*m.elemSize()`. You'll just have to ignore any additional columns, e.g. with `A_Eigen.block<0,0>(A.rows, A.cols)`.